# Función que a veces recibe un parametro extra

Tags: php, phalcon

Tengo una funcion que recibe 4 parametros pero aveces solo se le mandan 3.

me podrian ayudar a hacer esa validacion o como podria hacerlo.

Hice algo asi pero no funciono.

```
public function putAssignamentAccount($Agrupacion, $TipoPersona, $pais, $segmento = null)
{
    $model_get = new $this->modelClass;
    $model = $model_get::findFirst([
        "conditions" => "agrupacion = :Agrupacion: AND tipo_persona = :TipoPersona: AND pais = :pais:  ",
        "bind"       => ["Agrupacion"=>$Agrupacion, "TipoPersona" => $TipoPersona, "pais"=>$pais]
    ]);
    $cuenta  = $model->grupo_cuentas;
    $segmento = $model->segmento_mercado;
    if (is_null($segmento)) {
        return $this->buildErrorResponse(404, 'Error al relizar la consulta');
    } else {
        if ($model == true) {
            return $this->buildSuccessResponse(200, "SUCCESSFUL REQUEST", [$cuenta]);
        }
    }
    return $this->buildErrorResponse(404, 'Error al relizar la consulta');
}
```

No se cual habra sido mi error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes poner un valor predefinido en la función y basado en eso decidir:

```
public function putAssignamentAccount($Agrupa, $TipoPersona, $pais, $segmento=null){
     if ( is_null($segmento) ){
         //codigo si no viene la variable
     }else{
         //codigo si viene la variable
     }
 }
```

En este caso puse `$segmento=null` sólo como ejemplo, le puedes poner el valor que tú quieras y de cualquier tipo. Te dejo la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) de php que habla de esto.

Ejemplo de su uso:

```
public function putAssignamentAccount($Agrupa, $TipoPersona, $pais, $segmento=null){
     if ( is_null($segmento) ){
         echo "aquí no viene el segmento";
     }else{
         echo "aquí si viene el segmento";
     }
 }

 //llamado de la función con 4 parametros
 // imprime "aquí si viene el segmento"
 putAssignamentAccount('agrupa', 'tipo persona', 'pais', 'segmento');

 //llamado de la función con 3 parametros
 // imprime "aquí no viene el segmento"
 putAssignamentAccount('agrupa', 'tipo persona', 'pais');
```

Comment: hola, en tal caso me sigue pidiendo que mande un parametro no? en mi caso aveces no llega ningun valor

Comment: no entendí la pregunta, ¿entonces dices que siempre le pasas 4 parametros pero a veces llega vacio el ultimo?

Comment: aveces llegan 4 parametros y aveces llegan 3

Comment: sí, de que llegan 3 o 4 parametros si lo entiendo pero yo pregunto cuando los envias, ¿siempre envias 4 parametros?

Comment: no, hay ocaciones que se envian 4 y aveces 3 es decir aveces si le envio segmento y aveces no

Comment: entonces la respuesta que te puse si te sirve, ya la he editado con un ejemplo para que veas como invocar a la función en ambos casos

Comment: te agradezco mucho la ayuda